Programmatically generating/accessing SAML assertions for AWS CLI authentication
I would like to know how to programmatically generate/access SAML assertions from SSO IdP.
What I do at the moment is manually connect to SSO sign-in page in my web browser, use chrome devtools to download the SAML assertion generated from a successful sign on, plug it into my script and go.
Here's my script:
#!/bin/bash

cp $1 \~/.aws/saml.txt
dos2unix \~/.aws/saml.txt
ROLE_ARN="arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:roles/my/role"
PRINCIPAL_ARN="arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:saml-provider/sso.myorg.com"
ROLE_SESSION_NAME="TestECR"
SAML_ASSERTION=$(cat \~/.aws/saml.txt)

TEMP_CREDENTIALS=$(aws sts assume-role-with-saml --role-arn $ROLE_ARN  --principal-arn $PRINCIPAL_ARN --saml-assertion $SAML_ASSERTION --duration-seconds 900)

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $TEMP_CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $TEMP_CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $TEMP_CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')

rm \~/.aws/credentials
touch \~/.aws/credentials
echo "\[default\]" \>\> \~/.aws/credentials
echo "aws_access_key_id = $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" \>\> \~/.aws/credentials
echo "aws_secret_access_key = $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" \>\> \~/.aws/credentials

docker logout
aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin XXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com
docker push XXXXXX.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/repo/repo2:tag

Instead of passing this script my manually acquired SAML assertion, I want to generate it programmatically and simply pass the output to this script! Is there a way to do it? Is it just send requests.get() to the SSO url with proper payload k,v's?
I've tried sending a GET request to the SSO url, but received cryptic 400 error responses.
Thanks.
